# Excel how to sum rows that share a common attribute

Tags: excel

In Microsoft Excel, I have many rows of data that each start with and ID value. I want to sum all rows that have the same ID value into one row. How do I do this?

Example:

```
ID Fig1 Fig2 Fig 3
1    5    8    2
1    7    2    6
2    4    7    8
2    5    3    0
```

becomes...

```
ID Fig1 Fig2 Fig 3
1   12   10    8
2    9   10    8
```

Comment: If you want to do this in place it will require vba, Otherwise you can create the grid headers and use SUMIFS to get the numbers.

Comment: Could you be more specific about using SUMIFS?

Answer (score 1):

Using your example data then the sum of Fig 1 for ID = 1 will be:
=SUMIF(A2:A5,1,B2:B5)

i.e. sumif(range to filter by, criteria, range to sum)

Answer (score 1):

If you have your source data in `Sheet 1` ,use the formula in the other sheet in cell `B2`,

`=SUMIF(Sheet1!$A:$A,$A2,Sheet1!B:B)`

[image]

This is just one formula that you can drag it to right and then downwards to complete the formula for the entire range. Let me know if you need any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a pivot table.  Drag all the columns you need into rows and then the fields you need to sum in values.  By formatting the report layout as tabular and showing all the row labels, you aggregate the fields into single rows.  When you are done, if you would prefer not to have the pivot table functionality, you can copy and paste as values.